# Firebase Robotest logs not giving enough information for error or crash?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

Where should I look to see where the error is and what kind of error it is? I don't know where to look for roboTest when I get an error. It doesn't clearly show me the cause of the error. I can see which page I am getting error on.

I'm waiting to get more details about the error.

Comment: **We** should give you details about **your** error? How?